# Find the max value of $f(x,y)= 9\ln(x^2+2y^2+1)-x^2-y^2$

Tags: maximum

I need to find the max value of:

```
f[x_, y_] := 9 Log[x^2+2y^2+1] - x^2 - y^2
```

which has a center at the origin and radius 4. Maximize and NMaximize are not working because this problem seems to be too complicated, does anyone know any commands to solve this problem?

Comment: I do not get a failure from `NMaximize`. `In[193]:= f[x_, y_] := 9 Log[x^2 + 2 y^2 + 1] - x^2 - y^2
NMaximize[f[x, y], {x, y}]

Out[194]= {17.5133458211, {x -> 1.65548581653*10^-8, 
  y -> 2.91547593425}}`

Answer (score 8):

If I understand correctly, you want to maximize the following expression:

```
obj = 9 Log[x^2 + 2y^2 + 1] - x^2 - y^2;
```

subject to the constraint that `x` and `y` lie on a circle of radius 4. If so, you can do:

```
Maximize[obj, {x, y} ∈ Circle[{0, 0}, 4]]
```

> {-16 + 9 Log[33], {x -> 0, y -> -4}}

Comment: A `Circle` or a `Disk`? For newcomers it's worthwhile to note that `Circle` is indeed the case of exact radius only, while `Disk` also includes the inside.

Answer (score 6):

As mentioned by kirma in a comment to Carl Woll's answer, the maximum depends on whether you are defining the function as being on a [`Circle`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Circle.html) or on a [`Disk`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Disk.html)

```
Clear["Global`*"]

f[x_, y_] := 9 Log[x^2 + 2 y^2 + 1] - x^2 - y^2
```

Note that since

```
f[x, y] == f[x, -y]

(* True *)
```

there is a mirror of the maximum in either case.

```
maxCir = Maximize[f[x, y], {x, y} ∈ Circle[{0, 0}, 4]]

(* {-16 + 9 Log[33], {x -> 0, y -> -4}} *)

ptsCir = {{x, y, maxCir[[1]]}, {x, -y, maxCir[[1]]}} /.
   maxCir[[2]];

maxDisk = Maximize[f[x, y], {x, y} ∈ Disk[{0, 0}, 4]]

(* {-(17/2) + 9 Log[18], {x -> 0, y -> -Sqrt[(17/2)]}} *)

ptsDisk = {{x, y, maxDisk[[1]]}, {x, -y, maxDisk[[1]]}} /.
   maxDisk[[2]];

Show[
 Plot3D[f[x, y], {x, -4.1, 4.1}, {y, -4.1, 4.1},
  RegionFunction -> (#1^2 + #2^2 <= 16 &)],
 Graphics3D[{AbsolutePointSize[6],
   Blue, Point[ptsCir],
   Red, Point[ptsDisk]}],
 AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 12, Bold] & /@ {x, y, f})]
```

[image]